# What adventure has ever used a "Groundhog Day" plot?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons

We are considering writing an adventure using a *Groundhog Day* or *Edge of Tomorrow* approach where the party respawns at midnight or after a PC death but thought it would be good to take inspiration from previous efforts (or not bother if a great version has already been done.)

What published adventure has ever used a "Groundhog Day" type plot? As a fallback, podcasts or D&D streams would be acceptable (so at least the plot and play through are reviewable.)

Comment: Are you talking about written adventures designed for being played, or are you also asking about things like homebrew settings featured in popular podcasts and D&D streams?

Comment: Are you interested in a particular D&D edition?

Comment: @nick012000 It was an adventure, I'm sure, but I can't find it. I'm asking about it here: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/167919/4173

Comment: @nick012000 Please don't answer, even partially, in comments. [We try not to do that here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533).

Answer (score 8):

### The Ritual Repeats (*Children of the Night: Vampires*, 1996)

In the AD&D Ravenloft product *Children of the Night: Vampires* (1996), p.36, the vampiric ixitxachitl lord Myxitzajal possesses a cursed *pearl of enthrallment* which causes anyone within a one mile radius to endlessly repeat a single day. The item's description even specifically mentions the 1993 movie Groundhog Day:

> Its powers have been warped by the weird energies of Ravenloft. Now the pearl enthralls all victims (except the owner) within a one-mile radius whose Wisdom is lower than 16. Targets endlessly repeat the activities and emotions of a single day (this effect is similar to the situation in the movie *Groundhog Day*, though horrific rather than humorous). Victims have a chance to break the entrallment once a day by successfully saving vs. spell at dawn.

This book contains an adventure module called **The Ritual Repeats**, in which a small fishing village repeats the same day over and over due to the pearl's influence.

If a PC is affected by the pearl due to the party staying longer than one day, the module recommends that this is a good roleplaying opportunity. The player will of course know that the day is repeating, but their character should not, if they're affected.

### Lost Village of Janus Gull (*Dragon #367*, 2008)

The D&D 4e Eberron adventure module **Lost Village of Janus Gull**, appearing in the digital Dragon #367 (Sept 2008), the village of Janus Gull forms its own demiplane which is caught in a temporal loop. Its inhabitants re-live the same twelve-hour duration repeatedly, and are unaware that they are caught in a loop. On one day per year, the village reappears and can be entered.

Comment: Huh. I guess they've done it more than once, then? My exposure to it a bit where a whole Dread Domain was repeating, as a result of the curse levied on its Dark Lord forced to eternally relive the murderous drama that sucked him into Ravenloft to begin with.

Answer (score 7):

## An actual play (5e) podcast has done this

> The Adventure Zone: Balance Campaign (the first campaign) had a "chapter" that was structured around a Groundhog Day style plot. The Chapter is called "The Eleventh Hour" (Episodes 41-49).

You should note:

> The Adventure Zone's first campaign does not "strictly" adhere to D&D rules, but it is very good.

---

## There is a 3rd party published adventure for 4e has also done this

[Dungeon Crawl Classics #88.5: Curse of the Kingspire](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/170103/Dungeon-Crawl-Classics-885-Curse-of-the-Kingspire) does something like this (at least implementing a time loop in some form).

Answer (score 2):

## Die, It’s a Wonderful Gremlin Day

The [RPG ThinkTank](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qEZrRi5JVQs&list=UU0EkiSaci9rTVmc47LDHv2w) has published a Christmas adventure based on this. At a point in time or when a character dies, they all wake up back at 6am of that day.

The plot can be found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/rpg/comments/2q3vwi/6d6_4_christmas_themed_rpg_adventure_plots/):

> The characters awake at 6am on Christmas Morning. (...) The instant a character dies, the entire party once again wakes up at 6am on Christmas Morning to find everything is repeating.
>
> To unravel the mystery and find their way home the characters must save the suicidal man on the bridge, reunite a man with his wife, help a teenage couple defeat the small green monsters and discover the true meaning of love.

I've adapted this myself for a Chrismas Grinch adventure, but I haven't published my adventure yet. Maybe I'll update this post in the future.