# What is the name of this Ravenloft adventure where imprisoned PCs control NPCs in the past?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, published-adventures, product-identification, ravenloft

In this Ravenloft adventure, PCs suddenly find that they are now inhabiting the bodies of unknown characters at a ball held, as far as I remember, by Strahd von Zarovich at his castle.

> As the PCs are trying to go with the flow, most probably trying to escape the ball and the castle, some world-shattering event happens and everyone at the castle dies, with the PCs waking up as heads-in-a-jar on the shelf of some powerful Ravenloft NPC.
>
>  The NPC explains them that he has been able to transfer their conscience to the body of participants to the ball (henceforth PttB), which happened in the past. During the ball, something terrible happened and the NPC wants to prevent it.
>
>  They will be sent to the same instant in the past again, possessing a different set of PttB. The previously possessed PttB will do the exact same things they did while they were possessed by the PCs on the previous trip (so, for example, if PttB1 went and switched a lever in trip 1, it will do the same in trip 2, but PttB6 can run to the lever and jam it, or kill PttB1, if they discover that pulling the lever was a bad idea. Then on a later trip PttB13 can persuade PttB6 to let PttB1 pull the lever and so on.
>
>  Between trips to the past, PCs can talk to each other to coordinate a strategy. They only have as many trips as it takes to possess each PttB once.

**What is this adventure called?**

I remember the adventure being crudely formatted, so I'm not entirely sure it was an official one, but I'm writing anyway hoping that it was.

Comment: Another Ravenloft adventure-id question I was surprised not to see in the "related" sidebar: [What is the name of this Ravenloft adventure featuring a vampire innkeeper and a werewolf that kills villagers?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/167210)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're looking for "From the Shadows" (hopefully I'm not too late to answer).

The module includes the following text, spoken to the adventurers by the lich Azalin on page 10:

> "Now my fine, brave adventurers, you are going on a quest for me. I am sending you to a wedding. This is not just any wedding! This is the wedding of Sergei Von Zarovich. This wedding already happened—more than 350 years ago.
>
> “However, there is the small problem of your bodies. The lack of a head is of no consequence to me. Since I have no desire to lose such valuable servants, I'm keeping your bodies with me. You will inhabit the bodies of some of the wedding guests. You may do what you like at the party while I watch and learn.

Comment: It's never too late to provide a good answer; it looks like you may have hit the right one but it would be useful to fill in a bit more detail to support it. Welcome to RPG SE!

Comment: Delete voters - yes this answer is short and currently low quality. That said it might be the right answer and it's also the only answer that this question has garnered in over two weeks. I'm not sure deleting it is in the site's best interests. If the answerer doesn't come back and flesh this out then in this instance I wonder if it'd be better for a more experienced site user to do so on their behalf.

Comment: Here's a link to a supporting review, if anyone wants it: http://www.fraternityofshadows.com/DrawingRoom/Ravenloft_Products/Adventures_1_2_Edition/FromTheShadows.html Sounds like this answer is correct, if unsupported.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a quote of the most relevant passage from the module.